# What's the difference between 以後 and 以降

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I've seen these words used in the following sentences:

```
以後: それ以後彼女に会っていません
以降: それ以降彼は辛い一生を送った
```

Judging from these examples alone, I guess they have some kind of overlap.

When is it appropriate to use one over the other?

Comment: 以降：「以後」の意の漢語的表現。(明鏡国語辞典) /// 「以降」は、「以後」と同じ意味だが、「昭和30年以降」「終戦以降」などのように、比較的長い時間の経過に用いられる。(学究国語大辞典) <- tendencies, not fixed rules

Comment: Have a look at the best answer on this page: http://qanda.rakuten.ne.jp/qa1585994.html

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think of `以後` as meaning `one or more specific points after` whereas `以降` means `most of/the whole time after`.  But I'm not positive that they don't overlap at all.